# Запись строки из файла в переменную Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я новичок в программировании, прошу не кидаться камнями. Пишу переводчик на Python, необходимо считать строку из поля translate и найти аналогичную ей в slovar.txt если такая найдена вывести следующую строку из файла (в ней заключен перевод) в Label, иначе вывести 'Unknown word'. Выполняется по нажатию на кнопку.
В моем коде он выводит лишь 'Unknown word', даже если такое слово есть в файле.
Расположение слов в файле(ex):

```
дом
house
кот
cat
```

Возможно ошибка очевидная, и просто у меня проблемы со зрением. Заранее спасибо.
 Библиотека Tkinter

```
def translateclick(event):
    f = open('slovar.txt', 'r')
    count = 0
    for line in f.readlines():
        count = count + 1
        if line == translate.get():
            global sch
            data = line[count + 1]
            text_translate_otvet.config(text=data)
            sch = 1
            f.close()
            break
    if sch != 1:
        f.close()
        data = 'Unknown word'
        text_translate_otvet.config(text=data)
```

Comment: Я не умею писать на питоне, могут быть ошибки, но как-то так:) https://eval.in/931483

Comment: Error на ссылке

Comment: нажмите еще раз - тормозит сегодня сервак у них

Comment: Не помогло, работает ровно также

Comment: если работает, то посмотрите, нет ли конца строки? а так, должно работать

Comment: нет, не работает, проблема осталась таже

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def translateclick():
    with open('slovar.txt', 'r') as f:
        while(True):
            line = f.readline()
            if(not line): break
            if line.rstrip() == translate.get():
                text_translate_otvet.config(text=f.readline().rstrip())
                return 1
    data = 'Unknown word'
    text_translate_otvet.config(text=data)
    return 0


sch = translateclick()
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы словарь создать из файла, со словами перемежающимися с их переводом (каждое слово и перевод на отдельной строчке):

```
with open('словарь.txt') as file:
    words = filter(None, map(str.strip, file))
    ru2en = dict(zip(words, words))
```

Код убирает пробелы вокруг каждого слова (строки), убирает пустые строки;  оставшиеся слова читаются попарно и создаётся словарь переводов.

Чтобы показать перевод в translation Label слова указанного в word Entry (с помощью `StringVar`) после каждого нажатия клавиши:

```
def show_translation(*args):
    translation.config(text=ru2en.get(word.get(), 'unknown'))
```

Пример соответствующего Tkinter GUI:

```
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title('Ru 2 En')
word = tkinter.StringVar()
word.trace("w", show_translation)
e = tkinter.Entry(textvariable=word)
e.pack()
e.focus()
translation = tkinter.Label()
translation.pack()
root.eval('tk::PlaceWindow %s center' % root.winfo_pathname(root.winfo_id()))
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Очень благодарен